# Table Layout and API 15, can't set button text with java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a security app for an elevator company. The goal is to send SMS according to status of chosen elevator. I created the app with latest API and everything was working fine, but they bought "Huawei MediaPad 10 Link+" which has Android 4.2 Jellybean. So I had to downgrade to it.

My problem is button names were working fine with the latest versions. Now they are blank and I can only see the ones at the very bottom I added manually.

Here is the result:

[image: Here is the result.]

Here's my code:

````
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
//            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
//                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                    1.0f
//            ));
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);


            myLayout.addView(tableRow, lp);
            for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++){
                final Button button = new Button(this);
                if(i<elevators.size()) {


//                    button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
//                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                            1.0f
//                    ));
                    button.setLayoutParams(rp);
                    button.setPadding(0,30,0,30);

                    button.setText(elevators.get(i).elevatorName); //THIS PART DOESN'T WORK.
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    checkButton(button, elevators.get(i));
                    button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
                    button.setId(i);

                    final int finalI = i;
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            changeButton(button, elevators.get(finalI), finalI);
                            //sendSMS(elevators.get(finalI).elevatorNumber);

                        }
                    });

                    i++;
                    tableRow.addView(button, rp);
                }
            }

            if(row==13) {
                final Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setText("TÜMÜ");
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        btn_tumuneGonder();
                    }
                });
                tableRow.addView(button, rp);
                final Button button2 = new Button(this);
                button2.setText("GEÇMİŞ");
                button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                button2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
                button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        btn_Gecmis();
                    }
                });
                tableRow.addView(button2, rp);
            }
        }```
````

Comment: That `final` keyword is in every case completely useless, if not hindering.

Comment: You can use [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to check if the Buttons have the text set correctly (in this case it's more a layout issue) or not. What happpens if you do not set any padding and choose a smaller text size? (comment out `button.setPadding(0,30,0,30);` and use just 14 sp like so: `button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);`

Comment: @BömachtBlau commenting out "button.setPadding(0,30,0,30);" solved the issue. Thank you so much. I was going to add buttons and their click events one by one if that didn't work.

Do you have any idea why would that cause a problem in lower API? Maybe they have different default values in those?(Like px as default in API15 and em,rem as default in API29 etc.)

Comment: Padding is set in pixels whereas you set the text size in sp. This value is transformed into pixels depending on the device screen metrics. So it's better to also set padding based on dp. You can have a dimension resource with name="my_value" in res/values/dimens.xml and retrieve it by getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_value)

Comment: @BömachtBlau Got it, thank you so much. You saved me so many hours man :D